# Defer Amazon Redshift maintenance window using boto3 or CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, boto3, aws-cli

Amazon Redshift provides a facility to defer the weekly maintenance window [Managing Clusters Using the Console - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-clusters-console.html#defer-maintenance-window). The documentation shows how to do it via AWS Management Console.

Is there a way we can defer the maintenance window using Python Boto3 or AWS CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`modify_cluster_maintenance()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift.html#Redshift.Client.modify_cluster_maintenance):

```
response = client.modify_cluster_maintenance(
    ClusterIdentifier='string',
    DeferMaintenance=True|False,
    DeferMaintenanceIdentifier='string',
    DeferMaintenanceStartTime=datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    DeferMaintenanceEndTime=datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    DeferMaintenanceDuration=123
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This could seem strange, but I was searching for it on the same page yesterday and there was no mention of this.